# How to draw a line using RegionPlot?

Tags: plotting

I want to draw a vertical line x=1 with legend "x=1" using RegionPlot. I type the following code in Mathematica 11:

```
RegionPlot[x == 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> "x=1"]
```

However, the output does not contain the line x=1. What should I do to obtain the correct output? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: [`RegionPlot` will only visualize two-dimensional regions. Use `ContourPlot` to visualize one-dimensional regions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html#35219074).

Comment: @JHM Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @bbgodfrey et al - " is unlikely to help any future visitors " ? - Well, it helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, e.g.

```
Plot[{}, {x, 0, 2}, GridLines -> {{1}, None},PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}]
ContourPlot[x == 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
ParametricPlot[{1, u}, {u, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image]

You could "do" with `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[x < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> White, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}]
```

However, `ContourPlot`is probably what is wanted.

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu I am glad it was helpful. The flexibility in Mma is one of its useful and fun features.  Play (testing what different functions do)  has been very instructive to me.    :)

Answer (score 9):

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x == 1, {x, y}]]
```

Comment: What do you say to all the commenters here that RegionPlot does not work? - Best answer, imo.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html#35219074), `RegionPlot` only plots 2D regions.

`ContourPlot` is the function you're looking for.

```
ContourPlot[x == 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> "x=1"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`RegionPLot`expects an inequality; you are specifying an equality.

I suggest you use `ParametricPlot`as below:

```
ParametricPlot[{1, y}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to do this with `RegionPlot` as you may wish to overlay a region with a line x=1, use `Epilog` to add a graphic (in this case a `Line`).

```
line = Table[{1, y}, {y, 0, 2}];

RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}
          , PlotLegends -> "x=1"
          , Epilog -> {Red, Line[line]}]
```

[image]

Comment: What if the equation of this line is: z-y=1, where z is a variable which expressed by manipulate?